# What's wrong with my command? "The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to detect if a player has a score with this range, and if so, set down a redstone wire. It says "The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format" and doesn't work. Here is exactly what I put into the command block:

```
execute @p[score_direction=4,score_direction_min=3] ~ ~ ~ setblock 13 2 7 redstone_wire
```

I also had another command with a range of 1, not 2:

```
execute @p[score_direction=1,score_direction_min=1] ~ ~ ~ setblock 13 2 7 redstone_wire
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this command?

Comment: The error hints that there are no players with a score of `direction` between 4 and 3. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the command itself.

Answer (score 1):

**It's because it couldn't find any entity with the `direction` value between 3 and 4.** I tested this command with the executed command changed:

```
/execute @p[score_direction=4,score_direction_min=3] ~ ~ ~ say FOUND
```

The executing of the command was succesful after running these 2 commands:

```
/scoreboard objectives add direction dummy
/scoreboard players set rudygreg direction 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was because something was wrong with the command in the way I typed it (wrong type of brackets or something like that).